# Compare array of objects with nested array of objects and get unmatched array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-matching

```js
    const A = [
      {
        campaignId: "3964126695264",
        portfolioData: {
          portfolioData: [
            {
              asin: "B08FHG17ZH",
              sku: ["130511"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHF74TB",
              sku: ["130512"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHBWP89",
              sku: ["130513"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFL6GD",
              sku: ["130514"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHDWTK2",
              sku: ["130515"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFMW1V",
              sku: ["130516"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHF6V8B",
              sku: ["130517"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFWDVM",
              sku: ["130518"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFD18R",
              sku: ["130519"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08JKK4217",
              sku: ["130520"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08JKP82PB",
              sku: ["130521"],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        campaignId: "137244687845173",
        portfolioData: {
          portfolioData: [
            {
              asin: "B08FHG17ZH",
              sku: ["130511"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHF74TB",
              sku: ["130512"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHBWP89",
              sku: ["130513"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFL6GD",
              sku: ["130514"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHDWTK2",
              sku: ["130515"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFMW1V",
              sku: ["130516"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHF6V8B",
              sku: ["130517"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFWDVM",
              sku: ["130518"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFD18R",
              sku: ["130519"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08JKK4217",
              sku: ["130520"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08JKP82PB",
              sku: ["130521"],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        campaignId: "182862063246935",
        portfolioData: {
          portfolioData: [
            {
              asin: "B08FHG17ZH",
              sku: ["130511"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHF74TB",
              sku: ["130512"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHBWP89",
              sku: ["130513"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFL6GD",
              sku: ["130514"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHDWTK2",
              sku: ["130515"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFMW1V",
              sku: ["130516"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHF6V8B",
              sku: ["130517"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFWDVM",
              sku: ["130518"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFD18R",
              sku: ["130519"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08JKK4217",
              sku: ["130520"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08JKP82PB",
              sku: ["130521"],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        campaignId: "262747542546680",
        portfolioData: {
          portfolioData: [
            {
              asin: "B08FHG17ZH",
              sku: ["130511"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHF74TB",
              sku: ["130512"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHBWP89",
              sku: ["130513"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFL6GD",
              sku: ["130514"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHDWTK2",
              sku: ["130515"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFMW1V",
              sku: ["130516"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHF6V8B",
              sku: ["130517"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFWDVM",
              sku: ["130518"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08FHFD18R",
              sku: ["130519"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08JKK4217",
              sku: ["130520"],
            },
            {
              asin: "B08JKP82PB",
              sku: ["130521"],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ];

    const B = {
      ProductMetadataList: [
        {
          asin: "B08FHG17ZH",
          sku: "130511"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHF74TB",
          sku: "130512"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHBWP89",
          sku: "130513"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFL6GD",
          sku: "130514"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHDWTK2",
          sku: "130515"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFMW1V",
          sku: "130516"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHF6V8B",
          sku: "130517"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFWDVM",
          sku: "130518"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFD18R",
          sku: "130519"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKK4217",
          sku: "130520"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKP82PB",
          sku: "130521"
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKP82PB",
          sku: "13052221"
        },
      ],
    };

        let difference = B.ProductMetadataList.filter((page1) => {
      const result = A.forEach((element) => {
        element.portfolioData.portfolioData.find((page2) => {
          if (page1.asin === page2.asin) {
            page2.sku.includes(page1.sku);
          }
        });
      });
      return !result;
    });
    
    console.log("difference check ", difference);
```

Not able to achieve above result because the `page1.asin === page2.asin` is not matching you can `console.log(page1.asin === page2.asin)` and understand the difference as i am not able to explian.

I am trying to achieve:-
Comparing B array to A array and getting unmatched objects from array B.

Difficulties faicing:-
Not able to check if the value is present in array A - sku array from array B - sku value.

Comment: not sure what you are tryin to achieve but `forEach` doesnt return anything so your `result` is undefined

Comment: can u run console.log(page1.asin === page2.asin) and check?
the asin's are not matching because there are 2 loops running for array A.

Comment: maybe add an expected result as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just 2 lines

- make A array one level array - it will be easier to find a match
  `A.map(i => i.portfolioData.portfolioData).flat();`
- filter found element
  `B.ProductMetadataList .filter(i => !assinListA.find(j => i.asin === j.asin && j.sku.includes(i.sku)))`

```js
const A = [
  {
    campaignId: "3964126695264",
    portfolioData: {
      portfolioData: [
        {
          asin: "B08FHG17ZH",
          sku: ["130511"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHF74TB",
          sku: ["130512"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHBWP89",
          sku: ["130513"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFL6GD",
          sku: ["130514"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHDWTK2",
          sku: ["130515"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFMW1V",
          sku: ["130516"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHF6V8B",
          sku: ["130517"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFWDVM",
          sku: ["130518"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFD18R",
          sku: ["130519"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKK4217",
          sku: ["130520"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKP82PB",
          sku: ["130521"],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    campaignId: "137244687845173",
    portfolioData: {
      portfolioData: [
        {
          asin: "B08FHG17ZH",
          sku: ["130511"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHF74TB",
          sku: ["130512"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHBWP89",
          sku: ["130513"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFL6GD",
          sku: ["130514"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHDWTK2",
          sku: ["130515"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFMW1V",
          sku: ["130516"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHF6V8B",
          sku: ["130517"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFWDVM",
          sku: ["130518"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFD18R",
          sku: ["130519"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKK4217",
          sku: ["130520"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKP82PB",
          sku: ["130521"],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    campaignId: "182862063246935",
    portfolioData: {
      portfolioData: [
        {
          asin: "B08FHG17ZH",
          sku: ["130511"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHF74TB",
          sku: ["130512"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHBWP89",
          sku: ["130513"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFL6GD",
          sku: ["130514"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHDWTK2",
          sku: ["130515"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFMW1V",
          sku: ["130516"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHF6V8B",
          sku: ["130517"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFWDVM",
          sku: ["130518"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFD18R",
          sku: ["130519"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKK4217",
          sku: ["130520"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKP82PB",
          sku: ["130521"],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    campaignId: "262747542546680",
    portfolioData: {
      portfolioData: [
        {
          asin: "B08FHG17ZH",
          sku: ["130511"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHF74TB",
          sku: ["130512"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHBWP89",
          sku: ["130513"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFL6GD",
          sku: ["130514"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHDWTK2",
          sku: ["130515"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFMW1V",
          sku: ["130516"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHF6V8B",
          sku: ["130517"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFWDVM",
          sku: ["130518"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08FHFD18R",
          sku: ["130519"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKK4217",
          sku: ["130520"],
        },
        {
          asin: "B08JKP82PB",
          sku: ["130521"],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];

const B = {
  ProductMetadataList: [
    {
      asin: "B08FHG17ZH",
      sku: "130511"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08FHF74TB",
      sku: "130512"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08FHBWP89",
      sku: "130513"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08FHFL6GD",
      sku: "130514"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08FHDWTK2",
      sku: "130515"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08FHFMW1V",
      sku: "130516"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08FHF6V8B",
      sku: "130517"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08FHFWDVM",
      sku: "130518"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08FHFD18R",
      sku: "130519"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08JKK4217",
      sku: "130520"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08JKP82PB",
      sku: "130521"
    },
    {
      asin: "B08JKP82PB",
      sku: "13052221"
    },
  ],
};


const assinListA = A.map(i => i.portfolioData.portfolioData).flat();

const res = B.ProductMetadataList
.filter(i => !assinListA.find(j => i.asin === j.asin && j.sku.includes(i.sku)))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @Gass I am not using indexes in my code,everyone knows that the first argument in array-methods is `item` of array, it is not an index, where did you see index? if you want you can use any name taht you want

Comment: @Gass and what is not clear for you - to filter out found items and leave not found? it is so complecated business logic)) And I have a counter question - why you have written so complex solution?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, easy to read, would be to register the indexes of the `array B` of the matching data and then filtering by these indexes.

**Note:** I reduced the arrays to make the code easier to read. It will work with your data.

```js
const A = [
  { 
    campaignId: "3964126695264",
    portfolioData: { 
      portfolioData: [
        { asin: "B08JKK4217", sku: ["130520"]},
        { asin: "B08JKP82PB", sku: ["130521"]}
      ]
    }
  },
  { 
  campaignId: "137244687845173",
    portfolioData: {
      portfolioData: [
        { asin: "B08JKK4217", sku: ["130520"]},
        { asin: "B08JKP82PB", sku: ["130521"]}
      ]
    }
  }
]

const B = {
  ProductMetadataList: [
    { asin: "B08JKK4217", sku: "130520"},
    { asin: "B08JKP82PB", sku: "130521"},
    { asin: "B08JKP82PB", sku: "13052221"}
  ]
}

let indexes = [] // matching indexes of array B

for(item of A){
  let portfolioData = item['portfolioData']['portfolioData']
  
  portfolioData.forEach((el_A) => {
    B.ProductMetadataList.forEach((el_B, i) => {
    
      // conditions
      let C1 = el_A.asin === el_B.asin
      let C2 = el_A['sku'].join() === el_B['sku']
      let C3 = !indexes.includes(i)
      
      // save index if there is a match and the index has not been saved before
      if(C1 && C2 && C3) indexes.push(i)
    })
  })
}

let result = B.ProductMetadataList.filter((el,index) => !indexes.includes(index))

console.log(result)
```